# Update DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] value

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I have a DataTable which I and populating from CSV file on pageload event.

Before data is displayed to the user, I need to sort them by Date and then by hour.

It sorts the data just fine but when they are displayed again to the user, i want to format the date column so it displays in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

I am using following code to do that

```
DateTime d;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    d = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                    dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] = (string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", d)).ToString(); 
                }

            }
```

but the value of `dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j]` is never updated to the format I need.

I don't know why it is not doing it

Comment: [Link] (http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/178991/Sort-DataTable-Rows-in-Ascending-or-Descending-order-based-on-DateTime-in-C-Net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that data type in your Date cell is of string:

```
string strDate = (!(dt.Rows[i][j] is DbNull)) ? DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i][j]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "Unknown";
dt.Rows[i][j] = strDate;
```

you can go further:

```
string strDate = "Unknown";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dt.Rows[i][j], out date))
{
    strDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

dt.Rows[i][j] = strDate;
```

hope this helps.